# Change Admin URL

Tags: admin, url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I changed my Wordpress directory structure quite a bit.  Here's what I have:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/content');
```

So I have a **content** directory which contains my Plugins and Themes.  And then I have a **wordpress** directory which contains the core WP files, minus the wp-content folder.

With this new structure, I have to access the WP backend with this URL: `http://site.dev/wordpress/wp-admin`

Is there a way I can change it so I can just access it like so:  `http://site.dev/wp-admin`?

I don't want wordpress to be in the URL.  Would this be an htaccess update I need to make, or is there a setting I can use in my wp-config.php file?

Answer (score 0):

I've always just included a redirect in htaccess, but I'm sure there's a fancier way.

`redirect 301 /wp-admin /wordpress/wp-admin`